# PyCapsule but for raw memory locations

Tags: python-3.x

I am porting my embedded Python 2.7 implementation to Python 3.7 by using the C-API. I am looking for a convenient way to use the benefits of PyCapsule and PyMemoryView.

```
int size_of_foo = ...;
char* foo = malloc(size_of_foo);
```

`PyCapsule` does take a pointer, but no size or length information.

`PyMemoryView` takes a size or length info but has no destructor to free the memory when the reference gets deleted.

What would be your preferred way?